# How can I isolate a particular word/words in a string using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, substring

I have a dataframe where in one of the columns I only want to keep a subset of the string. In the example below I only want to keep the peoples names.

**Example: **

```
column 1
1.Joe Smith, NYC(212)
2.Jane Doe, HOU(713)
```

To remove everything left of the name I have used `df['column1'] = df['column1'].str.lstrip("0123456789.")`

This worked successfully. But isloltating the name from the comma onward is what I can't figure out. Not sure if RegEx would be better suited here?

Thanks!

Comment: First you need to come up with some rules that will consistently isolate the text you want (this depends on your data).  Then, to implement the rules, you could use the regular expression parser, [`pandas.Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) built into pandas.  But before you do that, why not search to see if someone has asked how to do this before?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to isolate part of string in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69707188/how-to-isolate-part-of-string-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: @Bill The only rule that would make sense would be that all names will have a comma at the end followed by the city and area code. I reviewed a few previously posted questions but hadn't come across the one you shared. I am reviewing it now, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with regex to extract names,

```
df['column1'].str.extract(r'\d+\.(.+?),')
```

---

**Output:**

```
0   Joe Smith
1   Jane Doe
```

More details on pattern,

- `\d+`: Match one or more digits.
- `\.`: Match a period (dot) character.
- `(.+?)`: Capture one or more characters (non-greedy) into a group.
- `,`: Match a comma character.